# Do I need "for" or "of" in a statement like: "<a fact> { - / for / of } which there is <proof>"

Tags: prepositions, reflexive-pronouns

Which is grammatical?

a. Tom denies a lot of the things he really has said. For instance, 'I have never been arrested,' which there is footage of him saying.

b. Tom denies a lot of the things he really has said. For instance, 'I have never been arrested,' **for** which there is footage of him saying.

c. Tom denies a lot of the things he really has said. For instance, 'I have never been arrested,' **of** which there is footage of him saying.

Comment: ...(for|of) which there is footage of him saying... is quite a mess, largely because of **of him saying**.  If you understand "footage of him saying" as a periphrasis for "evidence", I'd go with "for which there is {evidence}".  And is Tom saying that he never said those things, or saying that those statements are not factual? Tom denies saying many of the things he has said.

Comment: I would write "Tom denies a lot of the things he really has said. For instance, *he says* 'I have never been arrested' *when/while* there is footage of him saying *it/that*." I would avoid using "which" unless there is a reason you care to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of your sentences are understandable, if a bit awkward.

> Tom denies a lot of the things he has ***actually*** said.
>   For instance, 'I have never been arrested,' ***but***  there is footage of him saying ***it***.

Is still a bit awkward, more clear might be

> Tom denies ***ever*** saying "I have never been arrested." ***but***  there is footage of him saying ***it***.